# IdentityServer3 - What other ways to manage User Claim related to applicatrion?

Tags: authentication, authorization, identityserver3

Since Ids3 is used, same user can access two application ( App 1 & App 2 )

As a best practice am isolating the Role management and Application authorisation to the limit of the application.

By isolating, it looks to me the user is getting authenticated twice one by the ids3, the other by the application, like double authentication.

I am thinking of optimising this, when the application authorise the user first time, I will ask the application to send application related user claims to the ids3 server - user claim table (through web api exposed for the claim database/table).

So that next time user logs in, all the available claims will get added by the ids3, when user navigates to the application with required claims (ids3 will return all the claims), the application allow without application authentication. ( if required claims are missing then authentication can happen!)

If any required claims are missing for the application, with / without user consent, the application can update/add the claims in the ids3.

Is there any better way to implement this, application related user claims.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're seeing or asking... but I think you're asking if it's ok to cache claims in IdSvr for the user? Sure, you can cache them so you don't need to do multiple lookups in the DB.

Comment: Brock, your understanding is right, you said cache, but I am thinking to store the application related user claim in the AspNetUserClaims table, as I am using IdentityServer3.AspNetIdentity. From your comment, I understand it is not a bad option to store the application related claim in the data table.